# My gltf model cannot be shown in forge view

Tags: autodesk-forge

I exported my Revit file in gltf format. I was able to view this gltf file in various web and desktop viewers. No errors appear in the gltf viewers, but I cannot view my file in Autodesk Forge. Gltf viewers don't show any errors either. What is the reason of this?

Answer (score 0):

In Forge Viewer you can now load glTF files natively (in other words, without having to process them using the Model Derivative service) using a new viewer extension called Autodesk.glTF. Just like the Autodesk.PDF extension, all you need to do is load the extension, and then simply call the viewer's loadModel method, passing in a URL address of your .gltf file, for example, like so:

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer({ accessToken: '' }, async function () {
    const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('preview'));
    viewer.start();
    viewer.setTheme('light-theme');
    await viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.glTF');
    //viewer.loadModel('models/rac_basic_sample_project/gltf/model.gltf');
    viewer.loadModel('models/Sponza/glTF/Sponza.gltf');
});
```

Comment: This is the code block needed to open the gltf file directly. I open other gltf files, but I cannot open my own gltf file. This is the error I get"
"exception":"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mesh')"
" .

Comment: could you please share your file at deepali.srivastava@autodesk.com

Comment: Check your mail.