# My gltf model does not appear in Forge and I get an error like this

Tags: autodesk-forge

I exported my Revit file in gltf format. I was able to view this gltf file in various web and desktop viewers. No errors appear in the gltf viewers, but I cannot view my file in Autodesk Forge. Gltf viewers don't show any errors either. What is the reason of this?

```
Error while processing glTF: {"url":"http://192.168.1.99:9000//UploadFiles/f54491a3-d353-4a34-9c13-da51f9d5106e-965f1860-0e3a-11ed-aaa1-6b9ae0bdfb21/gltf/output.gltf",
"exception":"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mesh')","stack":"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mesh')\n   
 at t (blob:http://192.168.1.99:9000/29a28558-bd27-4a7f-97a0-2d5294cfeeca:17:26103)\n   
 at y.countFragments (blob:http://192.168.1.99:9000/29a28558-bd27-4a7f-97a0-2d5294cfeeca:17:26254)\n  
  at y.deriveInstanceTree (blob:http://192.168.1.99:9000/29a28558-bd27-4a7f-97a0-2d5294cfeeca:17:26647)\n    at y.loadRemainingGltf (blob:http://192.168.1.99:9000/29a28558-bd27-4a7f-97a0-2d5294cfeeca:17:21323)\n    at blob:http://192.168.1.99:9000/29a28558-bd27-4a7f-97a0-2d5294cfeeca:17:30200\n    at O (blob:http://192.168.1.99:9000/29a28558-bd27-4a7f-97a0-2d5294cfeeca:17:29069)\n   
 at S (blob:http://192.168.1.99:9000/29a28558-bd27-4a7f-97a0-2d5294cfeeca:17:29264)\n 
  at blob:http://192.168.1.99:9000/29a28558-bd27-4a7f-97a0-2d5294cfeeca:17:30484\n  
  at O (blob:http://192.168.1.99:9000/29a28558-bd27-4a7f-97a0-2d5294cfeeca:17:29069)\n  
  at Function.<anonymous> (blob:http://192.168.1.99:9000/29a28558-bd27-4a7f-97a0-2d5294cfeeca:17:30346)"}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My gltf model cannot be shown in forge view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73272926/my-gltf-model-cannot-be-shown-in-forge-view)

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73272926/my-gltf-model-cannot-be-shown-in-forge-view/73302027?noredirect=1#comment129454550_73302027